# Why sub-domain accessible through the main domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I have a web server with DirectAdmin installed, every time I create a new sub-domain (e.g xyz.domain.com) it will also accessible through the main domian (e.g domian.com/xyz)!!!

Any ideas on how to disable the access of sub-domain from the main domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to disable the access of sub-domain from the main domain?

You can place this rule as the **very first rule** in `/xyz/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^xyz\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: It's great, it's showing default forbidden error page but why it doesn't show my custom error page while I define it in my .htaccess?

Comment: If you have a custom page for 403 I think that should be shown.